# What size Integer is guranteed to be 4 bytes?

Tags: byte

How big does an Integer have to be in Java to definitely be 4 bytes long when converted into a `byte[]` using `ByteBuffer.allocate(int_value).array()`?

I ask this because I use Integers for Entity Ids in a game I'm working on and it's much cheaper to generate 4 byte Ids as as opposed to fill each `byte[]` with bytes that hold the value of `0x00`.

Comment: In Java, an `int` is always 32 bits (4 bytes), it does not depend on the underlying platform as in C or C++.

Comment: Note that the argument to [`.allocate(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#allocate(int)) is not the value, but the number of bytes to allocate.  If you want four bytes, you call `.allocate(4)`.  This will be able to hold any Java `int`.

Comment: Okay, it looks I didn't realise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand you, you're making wrong assumptions here. There is no conversion/truncation/expansion done with `allocate()` nor `array()` - you just allocate `int_value` amount of bytes, and get `bytes[int_value]`-sized array from `array()` call if `array()` is supported at all. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#allocate%28int%29

To make the array 4 bytes long, simply use `ByteBuffer.allocate(4)`, that's all. Then, if you want, use `putInt(somevalue)`, and you get 4 byte buffer filled with given int, because *that's the size of a Java `int`* (32-bits, as per https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), regardless of it's value.

Note: you're probably approaching this from a wrong angle, btw. It's best to use *big* buffers, giving you continuous memory regions, and simply segment them based on some metric, e.g. for 4 byte (int) cells, allocate 4*totalInts and then, e.g. get(4*i) etc, or use bulk getting.

Answer (score 1):

An integer (the primitive `int`) in Java should always be 4 bytes long hence the type isn't dynamic. See [Primitive Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

However, if your purpose is just to create an empty byte array, then just create it. There is no need to fill it with zeros hence in Java, the default value for bytes is 0.

If you want to ensure, that the byte array has the length 4, you could use

```
ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(int_value).array();
```

Comment: Of course you are right. I've edited my answer to make clear, that my answer deals with the primitive int and not with the object one.

Comment: it's just that in Java (AFAIR) "integer" is the usual way of calling the autoboxed type, while "int" is the name of the primitive; it's a source of some confusion, especially for greenhorns, and I pointed that out solely for that reason, since OP was obviously missing a couple of basic distinctions here.